# ctags : unable to create the tag for system verilog(.sv) files

Tags: system-verilog, ctags

ctags utility is not able to create/finf the tag for my SystemVerilog module  declared as below:

```
"(*ATTR*) module abc()"
```

If I declare it like:

```
"module abc"
```

then ctags is working.
Any idea how to fix this?

In both cases, I am able to see the `.sv` file in the tags file.

Answer (score 0):

Exuberant ctags is no longer under development, so your best bet is to test if that problem still occurs with [universal ctags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/ctags) and, if it does, report the bug there.